# I am using a prediction method for a website I'm making , I just need its name ( if it has one)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Im working on a website n stuff like that , And one of the functions the website does it that it predicts a few numbers , an example would work best here :

14 , 13.5 , 15 , 15.25 , 16 , X : these are the numbers I have and each one was taken a year , lets say im trying to predict the number that'll come next year that I called X.

The way I predict X is that I calculate the difference betwen each two variables : -0.5 + 1.5 + 0.25 + 0.75 = 2

2 /4  ( the number of differences I have access to ) = 0.5

Then I simply add 0.5 to 16 , making 16.5 my predicted next value .

I know this is by no means a good prediction method , but its what Im using right now and would just like to know it's name , thanks ^^

Comment: Note that your correction is simply (lastSample - firstSample)/numberOfSamples, in your case $(16 - 14)/5 = 2/5$. I doubt that this is very useful or has a name. – Btw, $2/5$ is not $0.5$.

Comment: I don't know what it is called, but I want to point out that in fact you are only using the values of the first and the last measurement, so you are basically extrapolating based on the end points, ignoring what goes on in the middle,  so you are totally correct stating that  "this is by no means a good prediction method".

Comment: I have corrected  the mistake I had there , But how am I only using the values of the first and last measurement ?

Comment: If you sum all the differences, you get the difference between the first and last number.

Comment: I'd call this "linear interpolation based on the first and last given values".

Comment: @JairTaylor I'd call it extrapolation though....

Comment: @JensRenders Sure, you are right, thanks.